# Create a view block that shows list of nodes that references same node as current node

Tags: 7, views, blocks, nodes

I have two `content types`. "Article" and "Collection". Any article can be placed into collection. Also when you create collection, you can select articles to be placed into collection. So I have created "collection" as `node reference` field in "Article" content type, and "article" as node reference field in "Collection" datatype.

Now when I am on any article page, I want to create view that shows other articles from the same collection. I have tried adding "collection" as `relationship` and `contextual filter` as "`NId`" with relationship with "collection", but it is listing all articles that is having any collection(may reference to other collection) and not the articles that belongs to collection of current article.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please suggest.

-- Thanks for your time.

Comment: Le me get this right you want your articles to be part of a collection right?

Comment: Yes, and while adding collection you can also specify the articles to be in the collection.

Comment: and you are using the entity reference field I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us assume the the filed in collection that referes to article is `field_entity_article`

Then you would do the following.

1. With in your view first you would add a relationship called **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** (A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_entity_article)
2. The you would add another relationship **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** (A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_node_article) While you are here select the previous relationship you created from the dropdown **Relationship**
3. Add a contextual filter of the type content: nid and provide default argument and select node id from url form the dropdown.
4. Add the required field and give the second relationship we created for this.

That should do it.

Comment: It is not working. It is listing all articles having collection.

Comment: could you show me a screenshot of the view you have created.

Comment: sure please give me some time.

Comment: Please go to: http://i47.tinypic.com/2d7g08n.jpg

Comment: I dont think you have tried the method I mentioned in my post. there would be two relationships. there will not be any relationship for the contextual filter as such.

Comment: I have added Content:Collection as relationship, and added contextual filters Content:Nid and added the created relationship. Also I have provided default value as "Content ID from URL", under when filter value is not available. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tried your method, but it was showing all articles having collection.

Comment: can you show me that a screenshot of that.

Comment: Please go to: http://i46.tinypic.com/33pc6fb.png

Comment: I dont think you have added the correct relationship.

Comment: you should be adding the relationship I mentioned in my post. it is not called Content:collection it should be called something like Entity Reference: Referenced Entity.

Comment: There was no such option available.

Comment: are you using entity reference for referencing the nides?

Comment: Oops sorry, I'm using node reference.

Comment: it would be better to use http://drupal.org/project/entityreference

Comment: But what is the problem with node reference, can't I achieve this by using it?

Comment: send me the link to the module you are using. For drupal 7 entity reference has much more than node reference. so it is a better approch

Comment: I am using: http://drupal.org/project/references

Comment: I think I have done this. I have added two relationships, Content:Collection and Content:Collection(Reverse), and in the field display, I gave relationship of Collection reverse

Comment: Here it is: http://i48.tinypic.com/24pdik5.png

Comment: did that work for you?

Comment: Yes, it worked, don't know how?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same approach as Mohammed, but found that the second Contextual Filter needed to be the Referencing Entity, not the Referenced Entity.

In essence, the first relationship identifies the Collection the current node is referencing. The second relationship uses the first relationship to identify any nodes where the Collection reference is the same as the current node.